# how to code a navbar so that buttons would take the user to different sections of the same webpage?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using HTML,CSS and Bootsrap. I want to create one static page with a Navbar on top, so that each button clicked on the navbar would take the user to different sections of the page.
apologies if my question is poorly formatted, I'm new to programming.

Comment: href="#whereYouWantToGo"  and then an id="whereYouWantToGo" to where to bring him

Comment: Use an `<a>` and set it's `href` to the id of the element you want to jump to, with a `#` before it, like: `<a href="#mysection">Jump to My Section</a>`

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.
Just place following code into the href-Attribute of your Anchor-Elements inside your Navbar:

```
<a href="#yourSectionName">
```

Then name the id of your sections of your page like so:

```
<div class="section" id="yourSectionName">
    ....
</div>
```